# Most stable Linux Distribution for Drupal?

Tags: linux, drupal

I have a VPS that is running Fedora Core 6, with yum somehow removed (Why do you do that Network Solutions?). I don't have an overwhelming amount of experience with any distribution of Linux, so I set up my own server running FC12. However, when I transferred over my Drupal site, I had some errors that I had trouble fixing. Granted, the PHP & MySQL versions weren't exactly the same, but were close.

My question is, is there any Linux distribution that is better/more stable for running Drupal? Or is the Linux dist. completely transparent to the website that is running on it. I am currently looking at centOS, Fedora, & Debian.

If you're a Drupal developer, can you share your experience running Drupal on the differnt platforms? Is it all the same?

Thanks!

P.S. No, this question doesn't belong on serverfault and No, I'm not asking which distribution is the "best".

Comment: "This question doesn't belong on ServerFault" really is up to the community, not you. If you ask me, this is more of a SF than a SO question.

Comment: This is about "servers" and "contains no source code", which exactly meets the criteria in the FAQ for Server Fault ... why do you say it doesn't belong there?

Comment: @Ken - This question is asking for the experience of developers, not server admins.

Comment: It's a server question, and it's one more likely to be properly answered by server admins. There are plenty of dual dev/admin folks (including me) over at SF.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I'm not saying you are this type of person, but there are people out there that live to try to get posts deleted for not being "relevant". The site is for the aggregation of information about programming and software development. right? So, if the post is even remotely associated with programming, it serves as a resource and should stay; regardless of whether it contains code or not.

Comment: "Programmers: what colour was your poop today?" is "remotely associated with programming", but that doesn't make it belong here. 

From the FAQ: "If your question is about networking, **servers**, or maintaining other people's PCs and **contains no source code**, ask on Server Fault."

Comment: @ceejayoz - Not everyone has the wealth of knowledge that comes with having 23K points. You may be both a server admin and a developer, but I am not, and I don't think that most people are. I deploy my own applications, as do many developers. Also, how many server admins (besides you) have a wealth of experience using Drupal? so, I'm sorry, but you're wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS is the most stable cost-free linux distribution. Also it's (main) packages (like php mysql apache etc) are tested for stability (not the lateast and greateast but the older and tested) and have security patches added up to date for their versions.
So CentOS should be best choice for your Drupal install.
BUT all theese are hardly an issue and your Drupal should run just fine with Debian/Whatever

Comment: How are you deeming it "most stable"? What benchmarks? What Linux distributions aren't applying security patches?

Comment: I deem it most stable based on my and my colleagues personal experience as server admins and programmers. I also deem it stable because it is it's (RHEL) state goal, because it uses older tested packages, unlike Fedora which is a feature testing platform for RHEL (= CentOS), and unlike Debian which is a general purpose OS. I don't think there is a benchmark that could test OS stability. Indeed most ditro's apply sec patches, but cetos'es older pkgs are less prone to vulnerabilities than newer edge like Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any significant difference for Drupal between the various major Linux distributions.

I've run Drupal on Ubuntu, CentOS, and Fedora. Other than typing `yum` vs. `apt-get` and slightly different package names, there hasn't been a single difference.

Answer (score 0):

The most important consideration is whether the distro meets the Drupal system requirements.

http://drupal.org/requirements

I have most issues with the php requirements.

> Recommended: PHP 5.2 for Drupal 5 and
>   6, PHP 5.3 for Drupal 7 Required: PHP
>   version 4.4.0 or higher for Drupal 5
>   and Drupal 6, PHP 5.2.5 or higher for
>   Drupal 7

With D6 some CCK modules have issues with php 5.1 and Drupal core + numerous other modules generate excessive warnings with php 5.3. So going for php 5.2 is pretty much mandatory.

Centos 5.5 installs php 5.1 by default.
Fedora 14 installs php 5.3.

You can upgrade and downgrade packages but it complicates the configuration.

Consult http://distrowatch.com/ for versioning info on the various distros.

Another option is to use a stack such as http://acquia.com/downloads but it targets a limited subset of distress.

Update: I recently was having issues with Drupal 6.17 on a Fedora 14 server due to the presence of php 5.3. However, updating Drupal core to 6.20 and all the modules (views, panels, cck, date + others) to the latest versions reveals that Drupal 6 is now fairly php 5.3 tolerant. Less popular modules may have not seen the required TLC however.